# Sonarqube error : The main branch of this project is empty

Tags: php, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, php-7.4

Today I installed sonarqube and sonarqube runner to scan my php project . But after running the scanner it shows **The main branch of this project is empty.** .

**sonar-scanner.properties**

```
#Configure here general information about the environment, such as SonarQube server connection details for example
#No information about specific project should appear here

#----- Default SonarQube server
#sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000

#----- Default source code encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8


sonar.projectKey=raka
# --- optional properties ---

# defaults to project key
#sonar.projectName=My project
# defaults to 'not provided'
#sonar.projectVersion=1.0
 
# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Defaults to .
#sonar.sources=.
 
# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Can anyone tell me what i did wrong? Please help I am new in PHP

Answer (score 3):

This error occurred because there are no source files that has been analysed by sonarqube because in the **sonar-scanner.properties**, you have commented out the analysis property `sonar.sources=.`

Sonarqube needs source files to be scanned so as to show the Sonar scan results. If there are no source files to be analysed then it will throw this error: **The main branch of this project is empty.**

Changes in **sonar-scanner.properties** file

```
#Configure here general information about the environment, such as SonarQube server connection details for example
#No information about specific project should appear here

 #----- Default SonarQube server
 #sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000

 #----- Default source code encoding
 sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8


 sonar.projectKey=raka
 # --- optional properties ---

 # defaults to project key
 #sonar.projectName=My project
 # defaults to 'not provided'
 sonar.projectVersion=1.0

 # Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Defaults to .
  sonar.sources=.
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had changed file suffixes for the language my code was.

```
sonar.ruby.file.suffixes = .rbt
```

It was .rb before, had changed it for some testing and forgot to revert.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. It can be resolved by either running the analysis inside the project folder or editing the 'sonar.sources' property with the appropriate path.